How can i do, instead of passing the same parameter, i.e. Customer& cust, again and again
I am currently working on a banking service project, on a beginner level. I am thinking to cut down on how I have passed 'Customer' class's cust object's reference as a parameter in each method of each class, in a way so that I am able to NOT pass 'Customer' class's object for a function definition.
class accounts;
class transactions;
class Customer;
class BankingServices;

class accounts
{
    public:
    int acc_no;
    std::string acc_password;

    public:
    void details(Customer& cust) const
    {
        std::cout << "Your Account number is: " << cust.acc.acc_no << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Your Account password is: " << cust.acc.acc_password << std::endl;
    }

    void add();

    void bal(Customer& cust);
};

class transactions
{
    public:
    int transHis[3];

    public:

    transactions()
    {
        transHis[3] = {0};
    }

    void transfer(int amt, int to_acc_no, Customer& cust);

    void withdraw(int amt, Customer& cust);

    void deposit(int amt, Customer& cust);

    void updateHis(int amt, Customer& cust);

    void showTransHis(Customer& cust);
};

class Customer
{
    public:
    std::string name;
    accounts acc;
    transactions trans;
    
    public:
    Customer()
    {

    }

    void details() const
    {
        std::cout << "Your Account number is: " << this->acc.acc_no << std::endl;
    }

    void create_cust(Customer& cust); // adds a customer and it's details into the database(it has add_acc() as a sub function)
};

class BankingServices
{
    public:
    Customer cust;

    public:
    BankingServices()
    {
        int val;
        std::cout << "Press 1 to create an account, if not a customer and don't have an account." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press 2 to enter account details ,if already a customer. " << std::endl;
        // taking input for 'val' and checking
        val = chkInputValfor2(&val);

        if (val == 1)
        {
            this->cust.create_cust(this->cust);
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Enter your first name: ";
            std::cin >> this->cust.name;

            std::cout << "Enter your Account Number: ";
            std::cin >> this->cust.acc.acc_no;
            
            std::cout << "Enter your Password: ";
            std::cin >> this->cust.acc.acc_password;
        }
    }

    void services()
    {
        int val;
        std::cout << "Enter 1 to withdraw money                 " << "Enter 2 to deposit money" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter 3 to transfer money                 " << "Enter 4 to check acccount balance" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter 5 to see transaction history        " << "Enter 6 to fetch account details" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> val;

        if (val == 1)
        {
            int amt;
            std::cout << "Enter Amount to be withdrawn: ";
            std::cin >> amt;
            this->cust.trans.withdraw(amt, this->cust);
        }
        else if (val == 2)
        {
            int amt;
            std::cout << "Enter amount to be deposited: ";
            std::cin >> amt;
            this->cust.trans.deposit(amt, this->cust);
        }
        else if (val == 3)
        {
            int amt, to_acc_no;
            std::cout << "Enter amount to be transfered: ";
            std::cin >> amt;
                    std::cout << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Enter account number to reciever: ";
            std::cin >> to_acc_no;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            this->cust.trans.transfer(amt, to_acc_no, this->cust);
        }
        else if (val == 4)
        {
            this->cust.acc.bal(this->cust);
        }
        else if (val == 5)
        {
            this->cust.trans.showTransHis(this->cust);
        }
        else if (val == 6)
        {
            this->cust.acc.details(this->cust);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong input! Enter again" << std::endl;
            services();
        }
    }
};

I thought of using inheritance but that didn't work. I thought inheriting customer class in accounts, transactions, BankingServices class would help, but it didn't. May be there is something i did wrong. I am expecting a way somehow I need not to pass the cust object's reference for every function.

why is transactions a class? What is int transHis[3]; ? Whats the relevance of an instance of that class?

IMO the input should not be part of the BankingServices class, and most certainly not part of the default constructor for that class.  What if you want to enter the information by reading a file?  What if the compiler creates temporary copies, and then the inputting of information pops up out of nowhere?  All of that code in BankingServices() should be a separate function that needs to be called explicitly, maybe run()?

anyhow, if a transaction needs a customer for its methods, what is wrong with passing a reference to the customer to the method  ?

Do not use inheritance to make passing objects easier. That's not what it's for. If Account is derived from Customer, you're saying that an account IS a customer and can be used as a customer. That's not a logical description of their relationship--customers HAVE accounts-- and you're opening yourself up for having to deal with strange bugs because an account can now be supplied to operations expecting a customer.

You should re-read the assignment you were given. Are you certain you are supposed to support a single customer with a single account? A good test of the transfer method would be to see if the other account (maybe even owned by the same customer!) received the money. In other words: Customers are there for the front-end, in the back-end everything talks in terms of accounts. Untangling the two concepts will make the transactions class make more sense.

Can a Customer have multiple accounts, such as checking and savings?  Can more than one customer, such as husband and wife, share the same account?

That's too much code for a [mre], so I'm going to pass some work back to you. As an experiment, what happens if you simply don't pass the Customer object as a parameter? (You don't want it, so simply get rid of it.) If you drop the parameter, so that (for example) the accounts::details() method becomes
void details() const {
std::cout << "Your Account number is: " << acc_no << std::endl;
std::cout << "Your Account password is: " << acc_password << std::endl;
}, what happens?
